# Xcode server builder unexpected error -with no access all files on my mac

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCiwX.png)

I set up the xcode server with invalid data. Now this error comes out + usually a window appears "Application "Hcode Server Builder" unexpectedly exited"

I want to reset server builder settings. I don't have access to all the files on my computer. But before that, there were enough access rights to configure the server builder